# JVM Heap Dump Analysis point to sun.awt.windows.WToolkit?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer, jide

I am analyzing memory leak in our application. After some investigation using **Eclipse Memory Analyzer** I recognized that the root which 'keeps' all references is `

> sun.awt.windows.WToolkit

[image]

And now I don't know how to interprate this result. I thought that sun.awt.windows.WToolkit shouldn't cause leaks. Maybe anyone has a suggestion how to interprate this result?

One of our ideas which we try to check is that it is caused by JIDE library which we are using http://www.jidesoft.com/ but it is hard to say if it has anything to do with it.

Comment: Finally we've found that the problem is caused by Jide component. However we catched this idea basing on some past experiences with the Jide library and it wasn't easy to find the error only by analyzing the heap dump, because the object which is keeping whole subtree was sun.awt.windows.WToolkit but not Jide object. What's more there was no direct connection between WToolkit and com.jidesoft.action.DockableBarManager. Is there any way to check through analyzing the dump which object holds the reference and which one is the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `ilog.views.chart.IlvScalableFontManager#dispose` solved our problem.

See [Class IlvScalableFontManager](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/jviewent/v8r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ilog.jviews.charts.doc/html/refjava/html/ilog/views/chart/IlvScalableFontManager.html)